# How to organize R scripts that use functions stored in R/ directory of R package

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I have the following package structure:

```
mypackage/
|-- .Rbuildignore
|-- .gitignore
|-- DESCRIPTION
|-- NAMESPACE
|-- inst
  |-- extdata
    |-- mydata.csv
|-- vignettes
|-- R
  |-- utils.R
`-- mypackage.Rproj
```

Currently I stored all the functions in `R/` directory. My question is 
where should I put scripts (e.g. named `try_functions.R`) to try the functions stored in R/, that scripts. It also use data stored in `inst/extdata/`

And in development process using RStudio, what's the workflow like to update and try the package after we add and fixed functions in `R/`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like [`testthat`](https://github.com/hadley/testthat) is the package you are looking for.  By "try", I presume you mean "test," and the way that it is canonically done for the `testthat` package is within a `tests/testthat` directory for the package.

Hadley's "Advanced R" book has a good deal [more information](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html) about best practices, and you can find many good examples by looking at github.

Some excerpts from the docs:

> Testing is a vital part of package development. It ensures that your
>   code does what you want it to do. Testing, however, adds an additional
>   step to your development workflow. The goal of this chapter is to show
>   you how to make this task easier and more effective by doing formal
>   automated testing using the testthat package.

And implementing:

> To set up your package to use testthat, run:
>
> `devtools::use_testthat()`
>
> This will:
>
> 1. Create a tests/testthat directory.
> 2. Adds testthat to the Suggests field in the DESCRIPTION.
> 3. Creates a file tests/testthat.R that runs all your tests when R CMD
>      check runs. (You’ll learn more about that in automated checking.)

You also might look at the [`rprojroot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rprojroot/vignettes/rprojroot.html) package for referencing various places within the directory of the package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `test` imply checking if the function works. By `trying`, it include testing and code that use the function fully, also manipulate data then store the output somewhere: e.g. plotting image, etc. Should it be also storedin `tests/tesstthat`?

Comment: I would argue so.  I would include what you consider `trying` in the definition of `testing`.  As you said: `testing` and using the function fully - making sure that it works as advertised.  The nice thing about the `testthat` package is that it is designed to _automate_ your checks, so you can run them regularly (of course you can always manually inspect the output).

Comment: Now one caveat.  It depends if the output is intended to live *in* your package.  I.e. is this output intended for "trying"/"testing"?  Or is this output that the user of your package will want to use?  If the latter, you may want to look into a `vignette` or implementing your execution into the `build` of the package or the load/attach (`.onLoad` or `.onAttach`).  The `devtools` package will likely be a big help to you in either case.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical place for keeping arbitrary R scripts is `inst/` subdirectory.
Note that tests of your package functionality it is better to put in `tests/` subdirectory. Loose scripts that are not tests (at least test of your package) should be in placed `inst/`. Those can be test scripts for checking deployment environment, test for checking production data quality, exec scripts to be plugged in crontab, whatever is useful/necessary in putting your package into action.

Quoting [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories) manual *"Package subdirectories"*:

> The contents of the `inst` subdirectory will be copied recursively to the installation directory. Subdirectories of `inst` should not interfere with those used by R (currently, `R`, `data`, `demo`, `exec`, `libs`, `man`, `help`, `html` and `Meta`, and earlier versions used `latex`, `R-ex`). The copying of the `inst` happens after `src` is built so its Makefile can create files to be installed. To exclude files from being installed, one can specify a list of exclude patterns in file `.Rinstignore` in the top-level source directory. These patterns should be Perl-like regular expressions (see the help for regexp in R for the precise details), one per line, to be matched case-insensitively against the file and directory paths, e.g. `doc/.*[.]png$` will exclude all PNG files in `inst/doc` based on the extension.